# Почему не работает плеер в v-for?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть плеер с сервиса *yohoho*(не реклама). Беру их скрипт, добавляю в index.html, затем беру div который будет отображать плеер и добавляю его в пустой компонент, он работает. Но если я его добавлю в такой `div`

```
<div class="movie" v-for="mov in movie">...</div>
```

И он перестает работать, почему? 
Мне нужно передать в div от сервиса yohoho имя нужного сериала, а он находится в `mov.name` как мне сделать? Можно ли в цикле к примеру назначить значение из `mov.name`  какой-то другой переменной и затем ее использовать в нужном мне *div*'e?

Код:

```
<template>
<div>
    <div class="movie" v-for="mov in movie">
        <div id="yohoho" data-player="moonwalk" data-title="Моана"></div> <!-- Так не работает -->
    </div>
    <div class="movie">
        <div id="yohoho" data-player="moonwalk" data-title="Моана"></div> <!-- Так работает -->
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    import axios from 'axios';
    import yohoho from './yohoho/yohohoComponent.vue';

    export default{
        data: ()=>({
            movie: [],
            also: [],
            show: true
        }),
        created(){
            this.fetch();
        },
        methods:{
            fetch(){
                axios.post('/api/get',{
                    id: this.$route.params.id
                })
                .then(res =>{
                    this.movie = res.data.serial
                })
            }
        },
        components:{
            'yohoho':yohoho
        }
    }
```

Comment: Код добавьте...

Comment: Добавил. Скрипт который я подключаю находится в `index.blade.php` С ним проблем нету

Comment: @Александр Если хотите протестировать, то можете зайти на сервис yohoho и протестировать, там есть раздел для вебмастеров

Comment: Я бы для исключения ошибок посоветовал бы навесить  index: `v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index"` Ну и в самом вызове вы не используете почему то обращение к текущим данным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так обратитесь

```
<div class="movie" v-for="(mov, index) in movie" :key="index">
        <div id="yohoho" data-player="moonwalk" :data-title="mov.name"></div> 
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/Rusic/pen/qJJrom вот тут пример, только id yohoho изменил на class

Comment: Попробовал, не работает.

Comment: Ошибок никаких нету. Внутри цикла не хочет работать этот плеер, он просто не отображается, и у меня есть догадка как решить эту проблему. в `data-title` я должен был ставить значение `mov.name` но так-как у меня нету доступа к циклу. Я думаю решить это как в php, вне цикла создать переменную, а в цикле к этой переменной ставить определенное значение, но вроде как это значение будет статическим, то есть не будет изменятся. А меня нужно так же сделать и тут, только чтоб было динамическое значение

Comment: А вы выводили `movie` ? возможно он пуст. Напишите выше дива  `movie: {{movie}}`

Comment: Да и еще одно при таком цикле у вас дублируются id, что возможно и приводит к ошибке. `id="yohoho"` в цикле не меняется.

Comment: id не может дублироваться, потому что в `movie` находится лишь один массив. ООооооо... точно... зачем я использую цикл... ведь в movie лишь один массив... я же передаю индентификатор в запросе axios, получается приходит лишь один массив... Поэтому можно не использовать цикл, ведь так?

Comment: Ну конечно, если данные одни зачем цикл.